# Song playing at the end of ep 127 of Fairy Tail

Tags: music, fairy-tail

What is the song, that starts playing at around 20:55 just when Natsu notices Lucy appeared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The song is Nakama Tachi, from the first OST. You can listen to it at [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vm3JIo5GNsg).